# Laravel is there any other way to display data from controller to blade?

Tags: laravel

Suppose I only selected one specific row from the database,
and returned that result to view.blade.php, now I want to display that single row of data. How would I do it without using @foreach is there any other function in laravel that i can use?

Comment: use `$row = Model::first()` method you will get a single record in the variable and in view you can access it like `{{$row->property}}`

Comment: @Arnel pls show your code what you did?

Comment: `@foreach (..)` in blade is just a template for `<?php foreach (..): ?>` there's nothing special about it other than this. If you don't need a foreach just don't use one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `first()` to get an object instead of collection. so you need not to loop through to get object property.

controller

```
public function functionName($parameter)
    {
        $value = Model::where('field_name', $parameter)->first();
        return view('view-name', compact('value'));
    }
```

view blade

```
{{ $value->property }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a record stored in $data variable now
you can simply display it on your view template like

```
`echo $data->image; //without using any @foreach loop`
```